# GitHub Footer ToolTip

Tags: html, github

What does **"0.18417s from unicorn-785bf9c5d8-mgr5g"** mean?

[image: GitHub Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this [old (2009) blog post](https://github.blog/2009-10-09-unicorn/), this refers to [Unicorn](https://bogomips.org/unicorn/), an an HTTP server for Ruby, similar to Mongrel or Thin.

So this measures the page rendition time.

This is illustrated during their [2017 move to Kubernetes](http://Kubernetes%20at%20GitHub)

> Before this move, our main Ruby on Rails application (we call it github/github) was configured a lot like it was eight years ago: Unicorn processes managed by a Ruby process manager called [God](http://godrb.com/) running on Puppet-managed servers

[image: Kubernetes]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the significance of it and probably someone from github could only be able to answer it.

But in general, that is the `title` attribute in `span` tag.

You can read more about the [title attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp)